# How to display the asset url path of an image within jQuery code in Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm trying to retrieve an image from my assets folder dynamically. The process of my code is that when the element is clicked, its parent element will change background according to the name  passed by the child elements ID. Please see my code below:

```
$(".flex-item").click(function () {
  // add class to div while removing it from others with same class
  $(".flex-item").removeClass("expand").addClass("vertical"); //declare the class of the element, remove expand class from all
  $(this).addClass("expand").removeClass("vertical"); //add class to clicked element
  var changebackground = $(this).attr('id'); //get id of clicked element
  $("#vaq-key-features-img").css({
    "background-image": "url({{ '"+changebackground+".jpg' | asset_url }})", 
  }); 
});
```

I have renamed my theme.js to theme.js.liquid. The url is being returned but the jquery variable is being read as a string and not displaying its value. See  below:

```
<div class="container" id="vaq-key-features-img" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1392/6087/t/3/assets/%22+changebackground+%22.jpg?8438893007511141278);"></div>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$("#vaq-key-features-img").css({
  "background-image": `url("${changebackground}.jpg" | ${asset_url})`, 
});
```

I've used `ES6 template literal`.

If you are using old browser where `ES6` won't support then try

```
var bgurl = "url('" + changebackground + ".jpg')";
$("#vaq-key-features-img").css({
  "background-image": bgurl, 
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Shiladitya, your alternative solution is executing but still its not displaying the correct path of the Shopify asset url. Its just giving the website's domain plus the name of the image but not the correct path folder where the image is.    `<div class="container" id="vaq-key-features-img" style="background-image: url(https://www.websitename.com/key-feature-01.jpg);">
</div>`

Comment: @ajnoguerra Which solution you took it? First or Second? What `asset_url` contains?

Comment: the second one. It displays this path within the style attribute as background when executed `https://www.websitename.com/key-feature-01.jpg` but this is the wrong one. Shopify asset url paths usually displays something like this `//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/392/6087/t/3/assets/vaquform-carousel-imageboxes-01_1366x.jpg?15627163126536874031`

Comment: okay I think I'm on a dead end with this problem. Found a few resources in Shopify forum about passing a [Javascript variable to liquid code](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/pass-variable-from-java-script-to-liquid-143782) and unfortunately you can't pass a Javascript variable to Liquid, because Liquid always renders first. I'll just find another work around to display the background dynamically. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a topic in the Shopify forum talking about passing a variable within the liquid filter and found out that it is not possible since [liquid filters](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/pass-variable-from-java-script-to-liquid-143782) are server side language. I did a work around with my code by using jQuery `attr();` I have added a data attribute within may parent container which will hold the id-name being passed by the child divs.

```
$(".flex-item").click(function () {
    // add class to div while removing it from others with same class
    $(".flex-item").removeClass("expand").addClass("vertical"); //declare the class of the element, remove expand class from all
    $(this).addClass("expand").removeClass("vertical"); //add class to clicked element
        var databg = $(this).attr('id'); //get id of clicked element
    $("#vaq-key-features-img").attr('data-bg', databg ); //pass id as data to container
});
```

Select the div with specific data and change background by using css attribute selector:

```
div[data-bg="key-feature-01"]{
    background-image:url('images/key-feature-01.jpg') !important;
}
div[data-bg="key-feature-02"]{
    background-image:url('images/key-feature-02.jpg') !important;
}
div[data-bg="key-feature-03"]{
    background-image:url('key-feature-03.jpg') !important;
}
div[data-bg="key-feature-04"]{
    background-image:url('key-feature-04.jpg') !important;
}
div[data-bg="key-feature-05"]{
    background-image:url('key-feature-05.jpg') !important;
}
div[data-bg="key-feature-06"]{
    background-image:url('key-feature-06.jpg') !important;
}
```

Since css file and images are stored in the same Shopify asset folder, specifying the path using liquid filter is not necessary anymore.